# Writing an applet that list all installed applets and packages on the card

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I want to write a program that returns AID of all installed or loaded applets and packages on Java card. In the other word, I want to upload an applet that when it received APDU Command=`xx xx xx xx` for example, returns those AIDs. (It is better to returns their Privileges and Life Cycles also,if possible.)

I searched **JC222VMspec**, **JC222JCREspec** and **JC222APIspec** for a method like LIST_APP for example! But I found nothing. I want to know if is there any way to do this? If so,how? Implementing a method or there is a method?

As a minor question, What is the difference between these three specification? I mean, when I want to write an applet for Java Card, which one of them I must read?

Comment: The function you want is already provided by GlobalPlatform-compliant cards, it is the GET STATUS APDU. Is there a reason you want to implement it yourself?

Comment: @mictter Yes, I want to know if is there any way to list installed applets and packages without MUTUAL AUTHENTICATION. as far I know the preodure tha GP implemented  to list applets, need this mutual authentication, I want bypass it.

Comment: You cannot install your applet without authentication, either...

Comment: @vojta Yes, you are right. But I want to see if I can upload an applet with a back-door to list AIDs, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In cards compliant to GlobalPlatform 2.2, there is a mechanism to list all application AIDs without needing to authenticate, for example from a User Interface application.

There is a catch though: this mechanism, described in GlobalPlatform 2.2 Amendment C, applies only to contactless applets. Anyway, my recommendation is to download the spec and have a detailed look at it. It is available from http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp (registration required).

Comment: Is there any way to write an applet on the card for this goal also? Just like the one that questioner wants.